# HTML textarea transferred to echo in PHP with line breaks as per user input

Tags: php, html

My `textarea` in HTML:

```
Description<br><textarea name="description" rows="5" cols="27"></textarea>
```

Within my PHP file I have:

```
$desc = $_POST['description'];
echo $desc . "<br>"; // needs line breaks as per user input in textarea.
```

The `<br>` I have used within my `echo` is simply there to place some room before and after the other content being entered when the form is submitted.

The text entered into the description box will show up when the form is submitted, however it is on one line and not broken up as shown in the `textarea` when the enter key is pressed.

How can I include the breaks from the description box into the PHP `echo`?

EDIT:
I used...

```
        echo "<pre>" . $desc . "<br>";
```

within my PHP file, works well. Thank you!

Comment: `nl2br()` or echo inside `<pre>` tags depending on whether you want HTML breaks or newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using:

```
echo $desc = nl2br($_POST['description']) . "<br>";
```

The manual for `nl2br`. Can be found in the link below

http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 1):

You can place the text inside a `<pre>` element, or any element with the CSS attribute:

```
white-space: pre;
```

And the white space, as well as the raw text, will be preserved (i.e. you don't need to modify the value you have been supplied).

Just be careful what you allow to be injected into your HTML, as all user input is unsafe and provides an opportunity for a number of HTML injection attacks.

```css
.output {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="output">This is sample output.
And it has line breaks.
So it is three lines.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $desc = nl2br($_POST['description']) . "<br>";
```

is a simple, one line solution :)